# Example of a Measure space

Tags: measure-theory, problem-solving

Give an example of a measure space $(X,S,μ)$ such that

[image]

Im a beginner in measure theory.

How do I approach these kind of problems?

Comment: That is not a typical question from measure theory, and I don't think expertise will help.  But it isn't a difficult question.  Think of combining measures on $\mathbb N$ with Lebesgue measures on subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: We arent taught about the lebesgue measure yet.Could you give an example without using it?

Comment: Find a measure on $\mathbb N$ whose values are 3 times the natural numbers.  And another measure on $\mathbb N$ whose values are $[0,1]$ (e.g. using base 2 expansion of the numbers in $[0,1]$).  And then combine these two measure spaces.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith What if the set is [0,1] U [3,c] instead of the  one given in the question. Is there any  condition that c has to satisfy?

Comment: These questions are unimportant puzzles.  If I solve it for you, there is no point to them.

Comment: Well these unimportant things may help when it comes to understanding the concept or the minute details one might  have overlooked, especially beginners like me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, but you get more out of the puzzle by doing it for yourself than seeing other people answer it.  It isn't a mainstream question in measure theory, so an expert has no advantage over you.